# How to move element relative to an element on top that varies in height

Tags: html, css

I added a ribbon effect to my h3 that looks like it's wrapped around my div. I just added a little triangle on the side and ordered it to be below the div and h3. I set the width of my h3 to 270px and the ribbon looks great is my h3 is a one-liner, but when the words occupy 2 or 3 lines, the h3 expands in height and blocks the triangle.

Is there a way to make the triangle move along with the height of the h3?

Fiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/MKMs6/)

```
<div class="gray-bg">
   <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
   <div class="triangle-l"></div>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet velit euismod, imperdiet purus a, semper eros. Aliquam lacinia tellus nec justo condimentum euismod non et dolor. Ut sit amet eleifend turpis. Pellentesque in adipiscing risus. Vivamus non accumsan nisl. Nulla accumsan velit ipsum, at aliquam arcu consectetur in. Integer vestibulum nunc a odio accumsan vehicula. Nunc at metus ullamcorper justo bibendum hendrerit. Aenean sit amet porttitor urna. Sed bibendum velit sed est eleifend, non cursus arcu hendrerit.
   </p>                  
</div>
```

Also my z-index is acting weird. The triangle has a z-index of 1, the div has 50, and the h3 has 100... but the triangle is still on top of the div when it should be on the bottom.

*Not sure what the best approach is - CSS or jquery - so I'm tagging both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd take a different approach, and create a pseudo element of the `<h3>` to create the triangle.  Also, you can make a triangle the exact shape you want, meaning there's no need for `z-index` to hide the top half, and you can position it `top: 100%` meaning it's always correct irrespective of the content within the `<h3>`.

HTML:

```
<div class="gray-bg">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
  <p>...<p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gray-bg h3:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent #4678A1 transparent transparent;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 0 15px 15px 0;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MKMs6/12/)**

Comment: of course!! i always forget :after! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make position `relative` and adjust `top` and `left`

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/feZbL/

```
.gray-bg .triangle-l{
    border-color: transparent #4678A1 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position: relative;
    top: -48px;
    left: -49px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you! i feel dumb, i should've known that it has something to do with position.

Answer (score 0):

Move the triangle into the `h3`, and position it relative to the `bottom` rather than the `top`.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pnXp/

Note that this requires you to change the `z-index` of the triangle to `-1` to position it behind the `h3`.

For bonus points, you can also do away with the `.triangle-l` element altogether, and use `:after` pseudo element to make the triagle!

http://jsfiddle.net/kE27U/

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to wrap h3 and the triangle in a div then position it relative

http://jsfiddle.net/MKMs6/8/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <div class="triangle-l"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### check your solution [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKMs6/13/)

Update `.gray-bg .triangle-l` class

```
.gray-bg .triangle-l{
    border-color: transparent #4678A1 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```